# What do the following chained statements mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I found this piece of code and I'm having trouble reading it:

```
require('happy module')
    .login('storage', { id:7, type:'foo' })(a, b, function c (err) { return err });
```

1) require('happymodule') is a function that takes one string argument and returns an object.

2) With that object, I invoke the login method, and passing two parameters, a string, and an object

3) which is returning a function that I pass three arguments
    (a,b,function c(err){return err});

Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes ................

Comment: Messy because it's written messy, it can look cleaner and more comprehensive.

Comment: It's not the best example of code in JS, but you got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) require('happymodule') is a function that takes one string argument
>   and returns an object.

Yes, but only because the `happymodule` modules has decided to export an object, it could have exported a function.

> 2) With that object, I invoke the login method, and passing two
>   parameters, a string, and an object

Yes that is correct

> 3) which is returning a function that I pass three arguments
>   (a,b,function c(err){return err});

Yes that is correct too!

Here it is written a little cleaner:

```
var happy = require('happymodule');

var login = happy.login('storage',{ id:7, type:'foo' });

login(a, b, function c(err){
  return err
});
```

Comment: thanks for expanding on the points.

Answer (score 0):

It could be written like this, if that makes sense:

```
var happy = require ('happyModule');
var login = happy.login;
var loginConfig = {
  id: 7,
  type: 'foo'
};

var useless = login('storage', loginConfig);

useless(a, b, function(err) {
  return err;
});
```